# Tetration convergence: prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} {}^{n}x = \begin{cases} 1, & n \text{ even} \\ 0, & n \text{ odd} \end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, exponentiation, tetration, power-towers

I'm a computer student, learning math just for fun. Today I was [graphing for fun](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9duwswjerm) that I found something strange! I noticed that that wired function ${x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{x}}}}}$ in zero, seems to converge to 1 when there are even powers and to 0 when there are odd powers! Then I attempt to prove it but I failed.

Then I did a little research and I found the [Tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) article on Wikipedia. This article says that my guess was right but without any proof. So I'm here to ask you about it.

> If we define ${x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{x}}}}}$ as ${^{n}x} :=\begin{cases} 1 &\text{if }n=0 \\ x^{\left(^{(n-1)}x\right)} &\text{if }n>0 \end{cases}$
>
> then prove:
>
> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} {}^{n}x = \begin{cases}   1, & n \text{ even} \\  0, & n \text{ odd} \end{cases}$$

Comment: I believe you should be able to do this by induction straight from the definition.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I don't see a simple way to apply induction... the $0^0$ form is indeterminate.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I mean the induction step. The base cases are trivial.

Comment: @DonThousand use strong induction, consider whether your case is even or odd, propagate top to bottom until it is reduced to one of the two base cases. I hesitate to write more since I want the OP to have a chance to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you want to approach this by induction. What is missing in to show that as $x\to 0^+, 1^-$, then  $x^x$ approaches $1$ from below.

**Step 1:**
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}x^x&=\lim_{x\to 0}e^{x\ln x}\\&=e^{\lim_{x\to 0}x\ln x}\\&=\exp\left({\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln x}{1/x}}\right)\\&=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1/x}{-1/x^2}\right)\\&=e^0\\&=1 \end{align}$$

**Step 2:**
$$\begin{align}\frac d{dx}x^x&=\frac d{dx}e^{x\ln x}\\&=e^{x\ln x}\frac d{dx}(x \ln x)\\&=x^x(\ln x+1)  \end{align}$$

**Step 3:**

Using step 1 above, the limit of the derivative of $x^x$ when $x\to 0^+$ is $-\infty$. But the only thing we care is that it is negative

**Step 4:**

If $1/e<x$ then the derivative of $x^x$ will be positive. At $x=1$, $x^x=1$, so for $x$ slightly less than $1$, $x^x$ is increasing towards $1$.

Comment: Nice! Isn't step 3 superfluous, though? $x^x=e^{x\log(x)}$ is continuous at $x=1$, and $1^1=1$, so...

Comment: @URL It's important that $x^x$ is increasing towards $1$ when close to $1$, and decreasing when close to $0$. You need that for induction. If you increase $n$ by $2$ you get closer to $0$ or to $1$, depending on $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that:

$$x^x=\exp(x\ln(x))=1+\mathcal O(x\ln(x))\tag{$x\to0$}$$

and in general,

\begin{align}x^{1+\mathcal O(x\ln(x))}&=x\cdot x^{\mathcal O(x\ln(x))}\\&=x\exp(\mathcal O(x\ln^2(x)))\\&\sim x\tag{$x\to0$}\end{align}

and

\begin{align}x^{\mathcal O(x)}&=\exp(\mathcal O(x\ln(x)))\\&=1+\mathcal O(x\ln(x))\tag{$x\to0$}\end{align}

from which you can easily see that it will alternate between being approximately $x$ and $1+\mathcal O(x\ln(x))$, and hence the limit alternates between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm leaving an answer so I can show an image. Note the red colored large kidney in the center of the image. [image: Escape of the exponential Mandelbrot map] It is the location of period one convergence and is referred to as the Shell-Thron Region (STR). Immediately to left of the center of the STR is a small yellow disk of period two convergence. Note that $^{\infty}1 = 1$ is at the center of the STR where $^{\infty}a = a$, while center of the yellow disk is $0$.

A pragmatic answer is that $1$ drives the dynamics of the surrounding exponential Mandelbrot map and that $0$ does the same, therefore $0^0=1$. In combinatorics it is common to take $0^0$ as $1$.