# Prove that $ \lim_{x\to 0}x^x=1$.

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}x^x=1$ for $\delta-\epsilon.$

We have to $|x|<\delta_{\epsilon}$ what will be chosen later.

$$\begin{align*}|x^x-1|<\epsilon &\Leftrightarrow -\epsilon<x^x-1<\epsilon\\ &\Leftrightarrow -\epsilon+1<x^x<\epsilon+1\\ &\Leftrightarrow \ln(-\epsilon+1)<x\ln x<\ln(\epsilon+1)\end{align*}$$

Hence I do not know how to continue, i.e. how to choose my $ \delta $. Someone help me, thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to assume knowledge of the limit $\lim_{x\to -\infty}x^2e^x=0$ in your argument?

Comment: No, sir. @AlannRosas

Comment: If you can find a way to prove that $\left|\ln(x)\right|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ for every sufficiently small $x>0$, a suitable $\delta$ will immediately follow from multiplying the inequality by $x$ and bounding the resulting right side (it's simply $\sqrt{x}$) by $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @AlannRosas You can prove that, if I'm not wrong for $ x <2 $. So for $ 0 <x <2 $, that inequality is true. And it would be.

Comment: That's correct. If you decide to go with this approach, the hard part of the proof will be proving this inequality. I'll spend some time on the problem to see if I get any clever ideas.

Comment: Oh sure, I'll try to test that, with derivatives to see what I can get to. And if I already try it, then I fix the x <2 and I would have my proof complete. Thank you :). @AlannRosas

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried using $\epsilon, \delta$ to show that $0 = \lim_{x \to 0^+} x\log x = ~$ [by Taylor Series on $~ \log (1 + u) ~] ~\lim_{y \to 1^-} (1-y)(-y - y^2/2 - y^3/3 - \cdots).$  Unfortunately this telescopes to $(-1) + [1 - 1/2] + [1/2 - 1/3] + \cdots = 0$, so I never get a chance to use $\epsilon, \delta$.

Comment: @AndrewMadison FYI, questions here which deal with solving your requested limit using techniques other than $\delta-\epsilon$ include [What is the limit of $x^x$ as $x$ approaches $0$ ($\lim\limits_{x \to 0}x^x$)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/752466/602049), [Different way solving limit $\lim \limits_{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ { x }^{ x } } $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1848004/602049) and [Tetration convergence: prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} {}^{n}x = \begin{cases} 1, & n \text{ even} \\ 0, & n \text{ odd} \end{cases}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3429034/602049).

Comment: Please take a look at this for an epsilon delta proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4113279/is-this-computation-of-lim-limits-x-to-0-xx-rigorous-enough

Answer (score 1):

The solution involves the Lambert function. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

First of all, $x^x$ is defined for $x>0$ and has a minimum at $x=1/e$

Secondly  the right inequality of the expression $1-\epsilon < x^x <1+\epsilon$ is true as long as if $\delta \leq 1$, and so it is true also for $\delta \leq 1/e < 1$

We focus on the left inequality and call $k=1-\epsilon \leq 1$ for simplicity.

We are looking for a value $\delta \leq 1/e$  such as $\delta^\delta >k$, and since $x^x$ decreases when $x \leq 1/e$ it suffices look for a $\delta$ that $\delta ^\delta = k$

The Lambert function is defined as $W(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ where $f(x)= x \cdot e^x$ and its domain is $[-1/e, \infty)$

Now we have some properties:

(1) $W(f(x))=f^{-1}(f(x))=x \hskip{1cm}$So $W(f(x))=W(xe^x)=x$

(2) $f(W(x))=f (f^{-1}(x))=x \hskip{1cm}$ So $x =f(W(x))=W(x)e^{W(x)} \Rightarrow e^{W(x)}=\frac{x}{W(x)}$

Now we focus in our search: $\delta^\delta = k \Leftrightarrow \delta \ln \delta = \ln k \Leftrightarrow e^{\ln \delta}\ln \delta =\ln k$

And applying Lambert: $W(e^{\ln \delta}\ln \delta) = W(\ln(k))$

If $z=\ln \delta$, the previous equation translates into $W(ze^z)=W(\ln(k))$

And since $W(ze^z)=z$ (prop 1), we have $\ln \delta = z=W(\ln(k)) \Rightarrow \delta = e^{W(\ln(k))}$.

But $e^{W(b)}=\frac{b}{W(b)}$ (prop 2)$ \Rightarrow \delta =\frac{\ln k}{W(\ln k)}$

So the solution is:

$\delta = \min \{1/e, \frac{\ln k}{W(\ln k)}\}$ where $k=1-\epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, I scrapped my original answer in favor of an $\delta,\epsilon$ approach, where L'Hopital's rule is not used.

I am re-interpreting the problem to be : 
To prove: $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x = 1.$ 
This is because, for any $\delta > 0$, there exists an $x$ such that $-\delta < x < 0$ and $x^x$ is undefined in Real Analysis.

---

For $~x > 0,~$ let $~f(x) = x\log x~$ and let $~g(x) = x^x.$ 
Then $~g(x) = e^{[f(x)]}.$

$\underline{\text{Lemma 1 :}}$
For $~0 < x < \dfrac{1}{e}~, f(x)~$ is a strictly decreasing function. 
Proof: 
$f'(x) = 1 + \log(x) < 1 + (-1) < 0.$ 
Thus, $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing throughout the interval.

$\underline{\text{Lemma 2 :}}$
Let $~\langle a_n\rangle~$ be defined by
$a_n = \dfrac{3^n}{n} ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$ 
Then $~\langle a_n\rangle~$ is a strictly increasing sequence that grows unbounded. 
Proof:
$\displaystyle \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 
\frac{3}{(n+1)/n} = \frac{3n}{n+1} > 1 ~: ~\forall n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$ 
Therefore, $~\langle a_n\rangle~$ is a strictly increasing sequence. 
Further, for $\displaystyle n \geq 3, 
\frac{3}{(n+1)/n} > \frac{3}{3/2} = 2.$ 
Therefore, for $\displaystyle n \geq 3, 
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} > 2$. 
Therefore, for $\displaystyle n \geq 4,
a_n > 2^{(n-3)}a_3 = 2^{(n-3)} \times 9.$ 
Clearly, as $n \to \infty, 2^{(n-3)}$ grows unbounded.

$\underline{\text{Lemma 3 :}}$
$x < y \implies e^x < e^y.$ 
Proof: 
$h(x) = e^x \implies h'(x) = e^x > 0.$ 
Thus, $h(x)$ is a strictly increasing function.

---

The challenge is that given any $\epsilon > 0,$ 
$\delta > 0$ must be found so that 
$0 < x < \delta \implies 0 \leq |g(x) - 1| < \epsilon.$ 
This will be true $\iff 1 - \epsilon < g(x) < 1 + \epsilon.$

In constructing a $\delta, \epsilon$ proof, $\epsilon$ will be arbitrarily restricted to be less than $1$, so that $0 < (1 - \epsilon) < 1.$

This is justified, since if a suitable $\delta$ can be found for a specific $\epsilon_1 < 1$, such a $\delta$ would also be suitable for any $\epsilon > \epsilon_1$.

Given $\epsilon$ such that $0 < \epsilon < 1$, use the following procedure to construct $\delta$:

By Lemma 2, $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ may be chosen so that

$$\frac{n}{3^n} |\log(1/3)| < 
|\log (1-\epsilon)|.\tag 1$$

Choose $\displaystyle \delta = \frac{1}{3^n} \implies \delta \times |\log(\delta)| = 
\frac{1}{3^n} \times n |\log (1/3)|.$

Note that for any $x$ such that $0 < x \leq \delta$, 
$\log (x) < 0 \implies x \log x < 0 \implies g(x) = x^x < 1 < (1 + \epsilon).$

Further, by (1) above, $\delta |\log (\delta)| < |\log(1-\epsilon)| \implies \delta \log (\delta) > \log(1 - \epsilon)$.

Also, since $\displaystyle \delta = \frac{1}{3^n} \leq \frac{1}{3} < \frac{1}{e}$, 
Lemma 1 guarantees that for all $x$ such that $0 < x < \delta, ~~$ you will have that $~~x \log (x) > \log (1-\epsilon).$

Invoking Lemma 3, this implies that $ g(x) = x^x > 1 - \epsilon.$

Comment: I know how to do it for L'H. But, I would like to know some way how to do it for $ \delta- \epsilon $. And well, I can't find a way. Thank u :).

Comment: It may be easier, but the OP explicitly asked for the use of the definition.

Comment: Excellent work!

Comment: @AlannRosas Thank you.