# Problem solving a limit without differentiation (L'Hopital)

Tags: real-analysis

I had this limit
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2^n}} $$ and I got it to:
$$ e^{\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\ln{(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2^n})}} $$
Now looking at the limit I have $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\ln{(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2^n})}$$
I don't see how to get rid of this $\ln$ or progress any further. Tried some substitutions but none seem to help. Managed to finish it with L'Hopital but formulation doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\frac  1{2n} \leq \frac  1 n-\frac 1 {2^{n}} \leq \frac 1 n$, so $(\frac  1{2n})^{1/n} \leq (\frac  1 n-\frac 1 {2^{n}})^{1/n}\leq (\frac1  n)^{1/n}$ for all $n$. Use squeeze Theorem.

Proof of the fact that $n^{1/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ wihtout L'Hopital's Rule:

$n^{1/n} =e^{\frac {\ln n} n}$ and $\frac {\ln n} n \leq \frac {2\ln \sqrt n} n \leq \frac {2(\sqrt n -1)} n \to 0$ where I have used the inequality $\ln x \leq x-2$ valid for all $x \geq 1$.

Comment: But how do i get limit of (1/n)^(1/n)? I'm encountering pretty similar problems like in the starting limit.

Comment: @Comizard Does [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237953/prove-that-displaystyle-lim-x-to-0xx-1/4237972#4237972) help?

Comment: $n^{1/n}\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: @Comizard I have edited my answer. Let me know if you want a proof of the inequality $\ln x \leq x-1$ for $x \geq 1$.