# $\lim_{x\to 0+} (x\ln(x))$ without L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Is there a way to find $\lim_{x\to 0+} (x\ln(x))$ without using L'Hôpital's rule?
I'm trying to solve this with squeeze theorem but couldn't figure out a lower bound.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237953/prove-that-displaystyle-lim-x-to-0xx-1/4237972#4237972) and consider that if $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+} |f(x)| = L \in \Bbb{R^+}$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+} \log~|f(x)| = \log ~L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\ln (1+t) \leq t$ for $t >0$ you can prove this using the following inequalities: $0\leq -x \ln x =2x\ln (\frac 1 {\sqrt x}) \leq 2x( \frac 1 {\sqrt x}-1) =2\sqrt x -2x$ for $0 <x<1$.